# How to copy a block of memory containing null terminator in c++

Tags: c#, c++, byte, memcpy

I have converted an image to byte array in C# and have sent it over TCP to a server application written in C++.

Now I want to copy this byte array to another block of memory. I've tried `memcpy()` function but the problem is `memcpy` copy the memory block until it reaches a null terminator ('\0'), and the byte array contains many of null terminators and I want them to be copied too.

**Update**

For simplicity I've converter the string "Hello\0"World\0" in C# to a byte array using the following statement:

```
string s = "Hello\0"World\0";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
```

I receive the bytes in an unsigned char* in c++ and copy it to another char pointer like this:

```
char *chars = new char[12];
memcpy(chars , recvChar, MESSAGE_12);
```

but the char* results in "Hello";

Comment: Your understanding of memcpy is incorrect. Have a read of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy  It just copies count bytes and does not stop on \0.

Comment: So you mean memcpy() is enough for me?

Comment: You may be confusing `memcpy()` with `strcpy()`.

Comment: No that's not possible. I'm using memcpy().

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving the 12 bytes? As others have said, memcpy doesn't check for any termination, so your problem might be before you reach that part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

The function `memcpy()` does not check for any terminating null character in source - it always copies exactly num bytes. You sure it was memcpy?

You can use something like this to print chars array (printf terminates at NULL character):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) //12 is the size of chars, I assume
{
    if (chars[i]!=NULL) //if you hit a '\0', ignore it
        printf("%c", chars[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I've even tried memmove() but the result was the same. I'm not sure what my problem might be.

Comment: @user3530012 do you mean to copy the data received byte by byte on the server side to a new array/memory block?

Comment: What do you mean of port? I connect in local using the ip 127.0.0.1 and port 8888. do you mean that?

Comment: @user3530012. could you please post a snippet to demonstrate the prob. its getting confusing at this point as to where things have gone wrong.

Comment: just one question, did you use 'printf' or 'cout' the chars to check it? or did you check all the 12 characters to confirm it? obviously, it will print to Hello, but chars[6] might contain the next alphabet @user3530012

Comment: Actually both chars and recvChars print "Hello" using printf()

Comment: i changed my answer. try out the approach

Comment: That's strange. it printed out "HelloWorld". What's the problem. Why I can't see the it in debug mode?

Comment: you won't be able to, all the printing functions terminate at null characters.

Comment: hope you got that all. best of luck!

Comment: So how can I be able to assign it to a string? I use string s = string(chars) but it just assign "Hello". and I need to send back the "Hello\0World\0" to the client too.

Comment: "Why I can't see the it in debug mode?": you can't see it in the debugger because the debugger displays the `char*` as a null terminated string since that's what they point to 99% of the time.  If you want to see what the `char*` is pointing to in the debugger, show it data in the memory window.

Comment: rather than using string, why not try vector<char>